# Transformation of sentence from compound to complex

Tags: sentence-construction

I tried but bit confused in applying the rules to transform the following sentences from compound to complex.

1. GIVE ME MONEY AND I SHALL SPEND IT.
2. WORK HARD AND YOU WILL SUCCEED.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. *Give me money and I shall* [*spend it*].
> 2. *Work hard and you will* [*succeed*].

They are already complex. "Spend it" is a subordinate (dependent) clause functioning as complement of "shall", and "succeed" is a subordinate clause as complement of "will" (assuming of course that one defines a complex sentence as one that contains an independent clause and at least one subordinate clause).

Note that in English there is a clause for every verb. Two verbs signals two clauses, even if one of the verbs is a modal auxiliary like "shall" or "will".

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are already complex sentences.

> 1. Give me money and I shall spend it.
> 2. Work hard and you will succeed.

The use of "and" here connects the 2 clauses in each sentence: "Give me money." with "I shall spend it.", and "Work hard." with "You will succeed.".

If you want them to *feel* more complex and formal, you can write:

(`If` sentences) 
1. If you give me money, I shall spend it. 
2. If you work hard, you will succeed.

(I'll update the examples if the comments can provide some more)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot comment on past comments due to my low reputation. In my view,they confused "complex structure of a sentence" with the literal meaning of "complex".In fact, your sentences are compound, as you said. But, anyway, I know what you mean by complex sentences so here is my revision:

> Give me money and I shall spend it

to;

> Give me money so that I can spend it (a result adverb clause)

and

> Work hard and you will succeed.

to:

> If you work hard, you will succeed